# How to pass array of array from javascript into php without ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

I want to pass a array of array from javascript into php. what is the simplest way to do it?

Array in javascript likes:

```
var resultArray = [ 
                    {"id":"1", "description":"aaa", "name":"zzz", "titel":"mmm"},
                    {"id":"2", "description":"bbb", "name":"yyy", "titel":"nnn"},
                    {"id":"3", "description":"ccc", "name":"xxx", "titel":"lll"},
                    {"id":"4", "description":"ddd", "name":"www", "titel":"qqq"},
                    {"id":"5", "description":"eee", "name":"vvv", "titel":"rrr"}
                  ] 

windows.location.href = "searchResults.php?resultArray=" + JSON.stringify(resultArray);
```

in the php I use:

```
$resultArray = json_decode($_GET['resultArray']);

echo $resultArray[0]['id']; // should be "1", but show nothing
```

Thanks in advance for every reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Its json_decode() not json.decode()

$resultArray = json_decode($_GET['resultArray']);
```

if you `print_r($resultArray`)  you will get a standard class array and you can access it by  `echo $resultArray[0]->id` and will give you 1;

Comment: Yuo are welocme @cecilfang

Answer (score 2):

**`json_decode`** will create objects for objects encoded as JSON. If you want an associative array instead, pass `true` as second argument:

```
$resultArray = json_decode($_GET['resultArray'], true);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: why can I not choose the both solutions as the answer *_*, sry!

Answer (score 0):

It's `json_decode`, not `json.decode`